# How to properly set netsh http add urlacl?

Tags: port, urlacl

I want to reserve a port for IISExpress 10 to serve a simple website to my LAN, but how do I properly use this?

````
add urlacl [url=]string
           [[user=]string
           {[[listen={yes|no}] [delegate={yes|no}]] | [sddl=]string}```
````

(I cut some of this ↓)

```
[url=] string
Specifies the fully qualified URL.

[listen={yes|no}]
Specifies one of the following values:

yes: Allows the user to register URLs. This is the default value.
no: Denies the user from registering URLs.

[delegate={yes|no}]
Specifies one of the following values:

yes: Allows the user to delegate URLs.
no: Denies the user from delegating URLs. This is the default value.

[sddl=] string
Specifies the SDDL string that describes the DACL.
```

So what do the `url`,`listen`,`delegate`, and `sddl` params do, and how do I use them?

Answer (score 0):

Good examples are on Microsoft's site:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/http/add-urlacl

You might get "Parameter is incorrect" which caused me some consternation.

Note that url must be a proper uri, http://+:8000 is not because its missing trailing slash, but http://+:8000/ is valid because of the trailing slash).  Also http://+:8000/MyUri is valid